# expose filter work with ajax only on inner pages but work with button submit on front page

Tags: views, ajax

What I want is to work expose filter with ajax only on inner pages but work with  button submit on front page i.e when I want my expose filter on front page to work like normal form but on inner page i want it to work with ajax

Comment: Are you doing this programatically, if so what code have you got so far .  you can use drupal_is_front_page() to give a boolean answer for what page you are on.

Comment: I am theming views exposed filters with some conditions
but how can i set ajax enabled only with inner pages

Answer (score 0):

Disable Use ajax in View settings, in `THEME_OR_MODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state)` function do like this:

```
function THEME_OR_MODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // dpm($form)
  // dpm($form_state)
  if ($form['#id'] == 'MY-VIEWS-FORM-ID') {
    if (!drupal_is_front_page()) {
      $form_state['view']->use_ajax = true; 
    }
  }
}
```

flush the cache.

Comment: i have tried it but with no luck

Comment: @harsh can you show what you've tried? It is working fine in my project..